# SWF to HTML5 Conversion Issues

Tags: html, flash, file-conversion, google-swiffy

Yet another Flash question from me. I've completed an interactive game (.SWF) with Flash CC (built with AS3), and I need to convert it to HTML5 for compatibility reasons.

I've taken a look at Google's Swiffy, which looked promising, but as you may be familiar, it only converts a file up to 1MB. Mine is 5.64MB. I can't use the downloadable Adobe extension because Swiffy doesn't support CC (yet?). I've also tried going the built-in feature via Flash, to convert the doc type to HTML5, but it's spawned more issues than it worth with my vector graphics.

I'd rather not rebuild the back-end as it is a LOT of code.

What might I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's complex or a lot of code, it's not a good idea using Flash and expect a good output in either of the available "converters" (Swiffy or Create). The same applies if you're using certain filters or various complex action with graphics (particles, etc.).

Still you can try moving outside the swf certain assets: maybe background images, sounds... And play/display them from HTML/Javascript.

If it's a large timeline-based animation (or similar), maybe you can split it, use various div-swiffycontainers and play them consecutively.